# Strange error message when launching iTunes 9.0 in Win7 (64bit)

Tags: windows-7, itunes, 64-bit

Yesterday I installed iTunes on my Windows 7 (x64) machine.  It ran for a time just fine but today when I went to launch it I got the following...

> "This operation has been cancelled due
>   to restrictions in effect on this
>   computer.  Please contact your system
>   administrator"

Well, I am my system administrator so that didn't help.  I know there are no policies in place to prevent it so that "restriction" wasn't it.

Checking Google and the like all seem to indicate this pops up with IE and is usually associated with a virus or malware.  I am 98% sure that isn't the case here as I have scanned, probed and otherwise diagnosed my machine and it came back clean.  (In case it matters I am running Kaspersky AV)

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
 I have uninstalled, cleaned, rebooted and reinstalled and the problem still exists.  I have also checked the "Image File Execution Options" in the registry and it looks clean.

Comment: I consider iTunes a "Potentially unwanted program", and apple updater is close enough to malware for me!

Comment: Well, I thought that went without saying. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installed location of iTunes may have been corrupted or compromised and therefore being treated as insecure to run.

Simply uninstalling, rebooting, and re-installing it may solve your issue.

Note: be careful of any possible loss of libraries/configuration in iTunes (possibly try to back them up).

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that and did it as well.  It didn't help.  I should have mentioned that in the question.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Are there any entries in Image File Execution Options for itunes.exe?

http://mygreenpaste.blogspot.com/2005/07/image-file-execution-options-good-evil.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  I looked and there is nothing there. :(

Answer (score 1):

You may want to investigate Group Policy, it can block image execution

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278839

> This issue may occur if there is a Group Policy object (GPO) that restricts what programs you can run. Programs can be restricted if either of the following policies in the domain organizational unit group policy or a local computer group policy have been applied:
>
> Do not run specified Windows applications.
>   Run only the allowed Windows applications.
>
> If you are an administrator, you can verify the policies that are enabled. To do this, click User Configuration, click Administrative Templates, and then click System.

If you're running a home edition of Windows 7 and don't have the group policy console, it appears that the settings map to:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960900.aspx

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, there are no policies in place.  However, I always enjoy a "backdoor" so I checked the registry entries and there is no "DisallowRun" Key at all.  This jives with what I saw in the GP console.  Thanks for the detail!!